# Trying to break up a string into list

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to convert a String into a List. I'm getting the string by user input, but whenever I run my code, and it gives me this:

> Enter a number: java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q�\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]

This is my code

```
public class ch3_15 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int compNum, user_hund, user_ten, user_one, comp_hund, comp_ten, comp_one;
    String s;

    //user input
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    s = input1.toString();

    //generating random number
    compNum = (int) Math.random() * 1000;

    System.out.println(s);

    //finding the hundreds, tens, and ones place of the user number
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(",")));       

  }
}
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Answer (score 2):

This is not error. It is expected behavior since you used

```
Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
s = input1.toString();
...
System.out.println(s);
```

and `toString()` returns String representing of object on which this method was invoked (in this case instance of Scanner).

If you want to use that Scanner to read line from user you should write

```
s = input1.nextLine();
//         ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't read the next String from the console, but rather convert the Scanner to a String, which you then print. 
What you want to use is `Scanner.nextLine()`, instead of `toString()`.

Also, this is not a runtime error, but simply a wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `scanner.nextLine()` to read next line that use enters.
Your current code is printing the `toString()` method of the scanner object and that is not a runtime error and is an expected behaviour.

```
//user input
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
s = input1.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not advancing from your current line; the method to use in this case is nextLine() from the class Scanner; So the code would be something like:

```
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
s = input1.nextLine();
String aux = s.toString(); // To return the string representation from the sc
```

nextLine() method from Java API 7 => This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.**/